# Increasing a value during merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have 2 dataframes

`df1`

```
product_id      value       name
abc             10          a
def             20          b
ggg             10          c
```

`df2`
Which I get after using `df2.groupby(['prod_id'])['code'].count().reset_index()`

```
prod_id         code
abc             10
def             20
ggg             10
ooo             5
hhh             1
```

I want to merge values from `df2` to `df1` left on `product_id`, right on `prod_id`.

To get:

```
product_id      value       name
abc             20          a
def             40          b
ggg             20          c
```

I tried:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby(['prod_id'])['code'].count().reset_index(), 
         left_on='product_id', right_on='prod_id', how='left')
```

Which returns `df1` with 2 additional columns `prod_id` and `code` with the `code` column holding the amount by which I would like to increase `value` in `df1`. Now I can just add those 2 columns but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: "Now I can just add those 2 columns but I would like to avoid that.": that does seem to be the simplest and clearest (and possibly the fastest) way; it's unclear *why* you want to avoid that.

Comment: I believe `pandas` has a procedure which would be the best practice for this type of task and I don't think mine is the one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s one alternative:

```
df1['value'] = df1.product_id.map(dict(df2.values)).fillna(0).add(df1.value)
```

Complete example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': {0: 'abc', 1: 'def', 2: 'ggg'},
                    'value': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 10},
                    'name': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'prod_id': {0: 'abc', 1: 'def', 2: 'ggg', 3: 'ooo', 4: 'hhh'},
                    'code': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 10, 3: 5, 4: 1}})

df1['value'] = df1.product_id.map(dict(df2.values)).fillna(0).add(df1.value)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  product_id  value name
0        abc     20    a
1        def     40    b
2        ggg     20    c
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `reindex` on df2 with the order of df1 product_id, after the `groupby.count` (without the `reset_index`). like

```
df1['value'] += (
    df2.groupby(['prod_id'])
    ['code'].count()
    .reindex(df1['product_id'], fill_value=0)
    .to_numpy()
)
```